# array.flatten( ) have parentheses ( ) at the end but array.ndim doesn't have parentheses at the end???? why?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

i was working with numpy, suddenly struck into a question
we have two functions 
array.flatten() and array.ndim

using flatten() without parantheses , return the address  of the object but with ndim, case is not same

```
import numpy as np
#array.flatten
#creating a 3D array
my_array = np.array([[['a']* 3]*3]*3)

print(my_array)

print('\n')
#using flatten to convert to 1D array
print(f"converted to one dimension ---{my_array.flatten()}")
print(my_array.ndim)
```

kindly explain whats the difference , code is displayes above

Comment: `flatten` is a class method, `ndim` is a class attribute. Please refer to Python class tutorials for the details.

Comment: Thanks for telling the answer